# SOLR : How to filter/not-consider search keywords like "the", "on", "in" that add no value

Tags: solr, stop-words

I am new to SOLR so have just got some basics right. I have configured parameters like mm, fq, qf, q etc but the problem is when a user searches like "a good italian chef in bay area", the search results (ranking) is getting affected by the presence of keywords like "a" and "in".

I know that there are some kind of settings/configuration to omit certain kind of words in SOLR but I dont know how to do that.

Thanks for help. I'm learning every day.

P.S. : I am using edismax

UPDATE :

I am searching against field information :

```
field name="information" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"
```

The search is working fine but the information is getting searched for some common occurring words like "the" "and" "an" "in" etc

Comment: We need more information from you please. Can you provide the `<fields>` section of your schema.xml and tell us what field(s) you are currently searching against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "stopword list".

You'll need to specify a file of stopwords and have the StopFilterFactory in your list of filters.  Details in the [Solr docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory).